# Returning Options of Class types in Scala methods

Tags: scala, generics, introspection

I am struggling with handling `Class` types for something I am writing, and the answer may involve generics, but I'm kind of stuck on what the right solution should be.

I have a Scala class `Vehicle` that has several child classes (`Car`, `Bus`, `Train`, `Motorcycle`, etc.):

```
class Vehicle {
    ...
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    ...
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
    ...
}
```

I now am trying to write a utility method that can map a String to a `Vehicle` subclass (that is, the `Class` it is, **not** an instance of that class):

```
object VehicleUtils {
    def mapToVehicleType(vehicleType : String) : Vehicle = {
        var vType : Vehicle = null
        if(vehicleType == "car") {
            vType = Car
        } else if(vehicleType == "motorcycle") {
            vtype = Motorcycle
        } else if(...) {
            ...etc.
        }

        vType
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm confusing/blurring types vs. instances. I don't want the `mapToVehicleType` method to return an *instance* of, say, `Car`. I want it to simply return the `Car` class if "`car`" is provided as input, etc. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry and what the solution is. I'd also like to use Scala `Options` if possible, because the `mapToVehicleType` method can certainly return `null`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? Your method returns an object of type `Vehicle`, not a class (type). Classes (types) are not objects and can't be returned, they exist in a parallel universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala provides `classOf[T]` to get the class type of a class. For example: `classOf[Car]` returns an instance of type `Class[Car]`.

For mapping to the appropriate class type, you can use pattern matching to map the types from the provided string to an `Option`:

```
def mapToVehicleType(vehicleType: String): Option[Class[_ <: Vehicle]] = {
    vehicleType match {
        case "car"        => Some(classOf[Car])
        case "motorcycle" => Some(classOf[Motorcycle])
        case _            => None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the class?  That's really the key question.  If you're going to dynamically instantiate using reflection you might consider a different pattern.

Reflection is one of those things that is often used to overcome the limits of Java (I'm going to assume that you are coming from Java).  But there's usually a better pattern in Scala.

You can return the class (e.g. classOf[Car]) but consider a better algorithm.

Let's say, for the sake of argument, you're returning the class as a "factory".  I'm not sure that's the best pattern but instead of reflection you might consider something like this:

```
object GetVehicleCreator {
  def apply(vehicleType: String): Option[() => Vehicle] = vehicleType match {
    case "car" =>
      Some(() => new Car)
    case "motorcycle" =>
      Some(() => new Motorcycle)
    case _ =>
      None
  }
}
```

Notice that it's not a "utils" object.    The use of "utils" is an anti-pattern in Scala IMO (honestly I don't like it that much in Java either).  Just create a function.  Anything with an apply method is a function.  To use:

```
val vehicleOption: Option[Vehicle] = for {
  fn <- GetVehicleFactory("car")
  vehicle <- fn()
} yield vehicle
```

... but again I'd have to know what you're trying to accomplish.  I'd bet there's a better pattern for it.

Comment: Thanks @john_omalley, I'm using Spark, and one of its API methods (specifically `StructType#add`) requires, as an argument, the class type of the new column/field you're adding to the struct. I'm writing a helper function that will allow me to convert string values into their proper Spark equivalents. So **yes**, I do need class types, not instances.